# Continue reading a list from specific point - Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of objects, saved by unique ids. Every time, I read several objects(decided by few conditions). That is done with for loop, using snapshot.getChildren(). My problem is how to continue reading the data from last retrieved object. Eg. If I have 10 objects in the database, I read 3 of them first time. Next time the app should continue reading from the fourth object, without going through already retrieved objects.

I researched about Query, startAt(), but it is allowing only search by value, not by id(my ids are firebaseReference.push()).

Code which I am using to point at specific value, but is not working:

```
public void getFeedPosts(final FeedPostsCallback feedPostCallback) {
    final ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    readFollowing = true;
    getFollowing(myID, new FollowingCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(final ArrayList<String> following) {
            referenceOnPosts().startAt("-MMequ1jrR1m73cKfgbt", "-MMequ1jrR1m73cKfgbt").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    try {
                        if (readFeedPosts) {
                            readFeedPosts = false;

                            Log.d(tag, "Reading feed posts");

                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Log.d(tag, dataSnapshot.toString());
                                posts.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class));
                            }

                            Collections.reverse(posts);
                            feedPostCallback.onCallback(posts);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(tag, e.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d(tag, error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the image: [image: Database]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the data and code performing the query that you're working with.  I suggest also reviewing the documentation to understand the capabilities of the database - you might be asking for more than it can provide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for the suggestion, I added a picture of the database I am trying to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursors in Firebase Realtime Database are based on being able to quickly find the anchor node in the list of potential results.

To do that you need to know up to two values:

1. You need to know the value of the property you sorted on, for the node you want to start at.
2. You may need to know the key of the node you want to start at, in case there may be more nodes with the same value for #1.

If you have both values, you pass them into `startAt()` (or `endAt()` if you want the final slice of the results):

```
ref.orderBy("propertyToOrderOn").startAt("valueOfProperty", "keyOfNode")
```

---

If you want to order/paginate on the key only, you can do:

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt("-MMequ1jrR1m73cKfgbt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since my property's value is custom class(it is not String), I  am not sure what should I add as "valueOfProperty". I added a picture of the database to the question, maybe that can help.

Comment: You'll need to know the value of the property that you order on, and pass that value in. If you have a Java object for the entire node, you can just look up the value of the correct property.

Comment: It is not possible to pas anything except String, Double or Integer as a value parameter. That is the problem. And if I put id as a, both, value and key(I am saving id as you can see), it does not continue searching. It looks like it is pointing on any child...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that reproduces where you are stuck. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the question. Now there is a code which I am using.

Comment: There's no `startAt` in the code you shared.

Comment: I am sorry, it was the old version of the code. Here is the active version.

Comment: You're missing an `orderBy...()` in the query. I update my answer, both for ordering/filtering on a property and the key, and only on the key.

Comment: Yeah, that was the key... Thank you very much, it is working perfectly now!